# Unable to set the JsonSerializer to Newtonsoft when using Azure function .NET 8 Worker with AspNetCore integration nuget

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I migrated from in-process Azure functions to worker/isolated which has the newer AspNet Core integration NuGet package(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#aspnet-core-integration).

I can't set the serializer to Newtonsoft so I can keep the old behavior for [FromBody] attribute.

My `Program.cs`:

```
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(workerAppBuilder =>
    {
        workerAppBuilder.UseWhen<AuthorizationMiddleware>(c =>
        {
            string triggerType = c.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values.First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger", StringComparison.Ordinal)).Type;
            return string.Equals(triggerType, "httpTrigger", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables()
               .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) => ConfigureServices(services, context.Configuration))
    .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(string.Empty, LogLevel.Information))
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();


static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    // other service registrations..
}
```

An example of a HttpTrigger function:

```
using FromBodyAttribute = Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http.FromBodyAttribute;

    public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(
            AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
            "post",
            Route = "companies/search")]
        HttpRequest request,
        [FromBody] SearchCompaniesQuery searchCompaniesQuery,
        CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(await companyService.SearchCompaniesAsync(searchCompaniesQuery, ct));
    }
```

What I've tried:

Option 1:
This works but I am worried I might break something with this code in the future, as I cannot find any docs, to understand if this would be supported in the future.

In Program.cs ConfigureServices extension.

```
    services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

and installed
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson Version="8.0.0`

Option 2:

```cs
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(workerAppBuilder => workerAppBuilder.UseNewtonsoftJson())
```

Option 3:

```cs
  .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>{
  
    services.Configure<WorkerOptions>(workerOptions =>
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        workerOptions.Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(settings);
    }) 
    
    }|)
```

The exception I am getting is:

```cs
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.528Z] Function 'createOrUpdate', Invocation id '172f2590-9810-48b0-8fa7-bdb1b02b1ea6': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.530Z] Result: Function 'createOrUpdate', Invocation id '172f2590-9810-48b0-8fa7-bdb1b02b1ea6': An exception was thrown by the invocation.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]. Path: $.repeatIntervalUnitsId | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 27.
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.534Z]
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.536Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FromBodyConverstionFeature.ConvertAsync(FunctionContext context, Type targetType) in D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FromBodyConverstionFeature.cs:line 91
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.537Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.Converters.FromBodyConverter.HandleResultAsync(ValueTask`1 result) in D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http\src\FromBodyConverter.cs:line 28
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.548Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Context.Features.DefaultInputConversionFeature.AwaitAndReturnConversionTaskResult(ValueTask`1 conversionTask) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Context\Features\DefaultInputConversionFeature.cs:line 103
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.549Z] Executed 'Functions.createOrUpdate' (Failed, Id=172f2590-9810-48b0-8fa7-bdb1b02b1ea6, Duration=343ms)
[2023-12-06T09:35:04.555Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Context.Features.DefaultInputConversionFeature.ConvertAsync(ConverterContext converterContext) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\Context\Features\DefaultInputConversionFeature.cs:line 43[2023-12-06T09:35:04.556Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.createOrUpdateTask. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
```

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Have you read my question?

Comment: I don't think `[FromBody]` is tied to a specific serializer. So can you create a custom `IInputConverter` that uses Newtonsoft, and register it, and hopefully it just works? [IInputConverter](https://techiesweb.net/2023/02/11/azure-functions-input-converters.html)